# How to query against TIndexCreator

Tags: ravendb

I have created this index:

```
public class ReceiptsByClient : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Receipt>
    {
        public ReceiptsByClient()
        {
            Map = receipts => from r in receipts
                              let d = LoadDocument<Debtor>(r.Receipt_Debtor)
                              select new { ClientId = d.Debtor_Client };
        }
    }
```

now I want to query against this index as follows:

```
var rptQry = Session.Query<Receipt, ReceiptsByClient>()
```

Of course I want to be able to pass a value for the ClientId in the Where clause.  However, the T of the where clause is of type Receipt, and does not know about the ClientId of the anonymous type defined in ReceiptsByClient.
How do I query using my ReceiptsByClient index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raven does [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) on almost everything involving matching queries to indexes.  All that you need is a type that has the field you want to query against:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

Then you use that in a query, and duck-type it back using `As` so your results are of the real class.

```
var q = session.Query<Foo, ReceiptsByClient>()
               .Where(x=> x.ClientId == "clients/123")
               .As<Receipt>();
```

Note that the `ClientId` field won't be in the results.  If you want to do that - you have to store the field in the index with `Store(x=> x.ClientId, FieldStorage.Yes)` and then use `AsProjection` in the query to duck-type to a class that has all fields.

Comment: what using statement to I need in order to bring As<T> into scope?